# Schedule Supabase Dart edge function to run at midnight every day?

Tags: dart, supabase, supabase-flutter

A couple of questions on Supabase edge functions in DART...

a). Running a job at mid night every day

I want to execute a job at midnight every day to perform various end of day data summarization and snapshot tasks.  Can this be setup as a DART edge function?  If so, how I would schedule this?  (Another reason for having these as an edge function is that I may wish to launch the 'end-of-day' process on demand via a web call).

b). Creating edge project within an existing client side Flutter project?

Can I create a new edge project a sub folder within an existing Flutter project? This is because I want to reuse data model classes already defined in the Flutter project.

Comment: In StackOverflow, you should only ask one question per post. Would you be able to split up your question into two separate posts?

Answer (score 0):

You can setup cron jobs using pg_cron and pg_net in Supabase.

Once you enable the extensions in your Supabase dashboard, you can run a query something like this to setup cron jobs.

```sql
select
  cron.schedule(
    'invoke-function-every-minute',
    '0 0 * * *', -- every minute
    $$
    select
      net.http_post(
          url:='https://project-ref.supabase.co/functions/v1/function-name',
          headers:='{"Content-Type": "application/json", "Authorization": "Bearer YOUR_ANON_KEY"}'::jsonb,
          body:=concat('{"time": "', now(), '"}')::jsonb
      ) as request_id;
    $$
  );
```

For more details, you can follow the official guide:
https://supabase.com/docs/guides/database/extensions/pg_cron

Answer (score 0):

there is another solution but I am not sure it is efficent or not.

1. create a table called MyCronTable .
2. create a cron with pg_cron to insert a record inside MyCronTable .
3. create a edge function on supabase that listen to the table for data insertion.
4. run the job if table data changes .

hint : you can hold the state of the Jobs inside  MyCronTable like (init, success, failed) with proper timestamp for logs.